# Cross compile Qt from Windows to Raspberry pi3

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-platform

I want to execute a application from windows to Raspberry pi3.
I use this link:
https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/
I do step 1 to 21.
For step 5 : qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.6.1.tar.xz
But when execute program I have this error:
Unknown modul(s) in Qt:multimedia

For test I create new project (Qt Quick Controls Application) but I have this error:
Failed to upload file "D:\test\untitled1"

Comment: The guess is to add -multimedia to configure step.

Comment: Step 12 ? How ?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html#including-and-excluding-qt-modules