# cross compilation of raspberry for qt from windows

Tags: windows, compilation, raspberry-pi3

How to do cross compilation of QT application on Raspberry Pi 3(stretch) from Windows Host machine. I have followed the steps from [here](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/) and also found some question on StackOverflow [Cross compile Qt from Windows to Raspberry pi3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602979/cross-compile-qt-from-windows-to-raspberry-pi3). I am stuck on step 12 and nothing seems working for me. Please help me out.

Comment: What exactly is 'nothing'? Please describe what happens and what you did beside the described steps to solve the issue, so we can narrow down a solution.

Comment: Hey,
This is the error i am getting whenever I am trying to do step 9 on (https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/)
$ which gcc
which: no gcc in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl)


I have added it to the environment variables.